# Button effects using OnTouch listener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

I want to add to my buttons some action. I want them to change color when you touch them and turn back to the original color when you move up your finger. But something goes wrong I couldn't find out what.

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean OnTouch(View v,MotionEvent mevent){
        switch(mevent.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"merhaba",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Button view=(Button) v;
                view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                view.invalidate();

                break;  }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{Button view=(Button) v;
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    view.invalidate();
                break;

            }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                        Button view=(Button) v;
                        view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                        view.invalidate();
                        break;
            }       }
            return true;}
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: sorry i dont mean to

Answer (score 1):

You can write on drawable xml file for button click effects. example **button_selector.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_image" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_image" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

put this drawable file as a background of your button. example

```
 <Button           
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
       android:text="Delete"
       android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Then background will be changed when you clicked on the button or focussed on the button.

Comment: Also put a `<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />` in the selector for a standard (neither pressed nor focused) button.